# Сменить уведомление

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Всем добрый день! подскажите пожалуйста такая ситуация, есть форма для подписки рассылки - вводим емейл и если все хорошо то пишет ( вы успешно подписаны ) если же такая учетная запись есть то выводится сообщение ( данный эмейл используется ) . Получается так что я ввожу почту которая есть и появляется уведомление что этот емейл используется, если же я ввожу новый эмейл которого нет абсолютно тоже самое. Прикладываю код, заранее спасибо кто отклинется! и еще просьба можно ли сделать при добавление новой почты ( которой нет)  скрыть див который с ошибкой.

```js
 $('#subscribe').on("submit", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var $target = $(e.currentTarget);
                var $inputs = $($target.find('.inputs'));
                var $success = $($target.find('.success'));
                
                
                $.post(e.currentTarget.action, $target.serialize(), function (data, status) {
                    if (status === 'success') {
                        $inputs.hide();
                        $success.show();
                    }
                }).fail(function () {
                    var errmsg = $('#errmsg')[0];
                    errmsg.innerText = "Данный email уже используется";
                    $(errmsg).show();
                });
            });
```

```css
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
$email = $_POST["email"];
$sql ='';
$nameFind = db::i()->selectCell("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT `email`  FROM `s_mailer_list` WHERE `email` = '".$email."' LIMIT 1) AS exist");
if($nameFind == false)
{
$sql = db::i()->query("INSERT INTO s_mailer_list (added,email,cats) VALUES (NOW(),'$email',',С сайта,')");
echo "Вы успешно подписаны";
}
else
{   
echo "Данный e-mail уже используется";
}   
}
$isAjax = is_ajax();
 if ($isAjax) {
                    header('Content-Type: application/json');
                    $data = [];
                    if ($sql) {
                        $data['success'] = true;
                    } else {
                        http_response_code(400);
                        $data['message'] = 'Данный email уже используется ';
                    }

                    echo json_encode($data);
                }
```

```html
  <form class="subscribe" id="subscribe" method="POST" action="subscribe.php"> 
                            <p>Подписка на информационную рассылку</p>
                            <div class="inputs">
                            <div class="d-flex">
                                <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" id="email" required placeholder="Email">
                                <button class="btn" type="submit" name="submit_form" value="submit">
                                    <img src="/newdev/images/arrow-submit.svg" alt="">
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                             <div class="success" style="display: none; text-align:center; color:rgb(53 58 54); padding:6px 6px 6px 6px; background:#FFFFFF; border-radius:6px;">Вы успешно подписаны &#9745;</div>
                             <div class="errmsg" id="errmsg"  style="display: none; text-align:center; color:rgb(53 58 54); padding:6px 6px 6px 6px; background:#FFFFFF; border-radius:6px;">Данный email уже используется</div>
                        </form>
```

Comment: Что такое selectCell и что оно делает? Банально, проверить надо что $nameFind

Comment: Я так понимаю что это выбирает ячейку из бд , это по движку так